# OSGi Container - Equinox vs Apache Felix inside Apache Karaf

Tags: apache-karaf, equinox

Started working on a new project and We are using Apache Karaf for running OSGi bundles. Some one suggested me to use Equinox instead of Felix inside Karaf. Please some body let me know if Equinox is better than Felix and if so what way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few years ago there were some stability issues that lead folks to recommend Equinox over Felix. Today, I recommend using Felix since a good number of the Karaf/ServiceMix committers also have the ability to make changes to Felix without having to wait for Equinox to make upstream changes.

Latest check of Equinox website also seems to indicate that it is lagging Felix+Karaf a bit in terms of adopting the latest OSGi Enterprise specs.